# How to re-synchronise emails received using pop protocol with server

Tags: email, sync, imap, pop3

I have used Thunderbid with the same email address during many years using the `pop` protocol because I used to read emails on one device only.

Now I read them on multiple devices using `imap`, and I'm looking for a solution to synchronize back (or re-synchronize) **old emails** to other devices.

- I'm not looking for a solution for new emails, but for the
  already-donwloaded-with-pop emails that have been deleted from server,
  and are only stored locally on my computer.
- I'm **not** looking for a `Thunderbid` specific solution. I'm now also receiving emails with `Geary` on `ubuntu` and default `android 6` mail application
- I'm now using the "*do not delete from server*" option for a while, but I haven't always did.
- My question is about my ISP email (French ISP "`Free`", domain `free.fr`, web access based on `zimbra`)
- Best solution would involve synchronize both received and send emails
- I keep emails organized in (too) many folders *locally*. And now I also have `imap` folders.
- I don't mind messing around with these folders and reorganize them after synchronization is complete, but it would be nice to  also synchronize folders and keep my 15 years archive organized

Comment: I might have found a solution [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/198559/how-to-import-your-pop3-emails-into-an-imap-account/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like it was as simple as a "drag and drop" !

1. Add `imap` account next to `pop` account into `Thunderbird`
2. Drag and drop emails from `pop` account to `imap` account.
3. Done !

[source](http://www.howtogeek.com/198559/how-to-import-your-pop3-emails-into-an-imap-account/)